# The use of "TL;DR" in answers

Tags: discussion

Does anyone have an opinion on this?  I feel like it makes an answer less readable to explicitly state:

TL;DR and then provide a summary.

Especially since this shorthand is not necessarily known to the greater world...  personally, I'd prefer we attempt to discourage it's use, but I figured it could be a topic of discussion.

TL;DR -- Yes or no (TL;DR) ?

Answer (score 12):

Yes *and* no.  The best answers lead with a natural "TL;DR-ish" introduction -- such that no actual TL;DR is required.

Answer (score 2):

I think [**tl;dr**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10659/what-does-tldr-mean#10664) is justified if it arises as a postscript in a subsequent edit.  It is not ideally readable style, but if many people might be rereading the answer, they might find it easier to follow the changes to the answer.

Making the shortahd a clickable link, as I did above, deals with the unfamiliarity concern.

I would not recommend editing answers to eliminate this construct.

Comment: Could having tl;dr auto-link fix these problems?

Comment: @Pure: I guess it would help.  I don't think the problem is so serious that it needs this kind of fix.